# How to check Accelerometer presence on Windows Machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I need to find whether Accelerometer is present on Windows XP/7/8/10 Device in C# Windows Form Application. I am not able to find any support on msdn, Please help me out.

Comment: Why do you have both [tag:asp.net] and [tag:winforms] tags? What .NET framework? I don't think XP supported the "Sensors" that 7/8/10 does, so for XP it would have to be a device-specific API.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.devices.sensors.accelerometer.aspx Here is the class but I doubt you will be sucessful with XP and sensors